# Can I set variable value by name in another variable in PowerShell

Tags: php, powershell, variables

In *PHP* I can write that code:

```
$var = 1;
$name = 'var';
$$name = 2;
echo "var = $var";
```

Result: `var = 2`

How can I do things like that in PowerShell?

I tried:

- `$$name = 2`
  `Unexpected token 'name' in expression or statement.`
- `${$name} = 2`
  Creates variable with name **$name**

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by assigning a variable by reference.

```
$var = 1
$name = [ref]$var
$name.Value = 2
$var # outputs 2
```